# How to access session variable in layout

Tags: php, yii2

In the controller of login(actionLogin) i have created session & on successful login i have set session variables & rendered the page dashboard.

In the dashboard i have tried echoing that session variable in the layout of main.php which is my menubar.

```
<?php echo $session['name']; ?>
```

I have opened the session in the menubar as

```
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?php $session->open();?>
```

it is showing me error that calling to non-object method open.

I have also added use yii\web\session on the top.

How to access the session in the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->session['name']; ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html